# C# - Passing an Object Parameter into a list.Find function

Tags: c#

I am writing a Find function for a list that requires me to pass in an Object as a parameter. The reason for this is that the Find function uses some variables in the currently focused Object (CFO) to find the next object (The X and Y co-ordinates).

The Find function looks for the first object it can find within a box region, using the X,Y of the currently focused Object to create the box region. The problem I am having is I can not figure out how to pass the object in as a parameter for the Find function.

Does anyone have a solution? I can't seem to find anything on Stackoverflow or Google.

Comment: You're looking to use something like [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx) but to be honest with you, you're better off bashing out a solution with out linq first. Linq is really only for linear stuff, not recursive stuff.

Comment: @Yuval - There is no code for this function yet. All I have right now is a list sorted in the order of Objects being the first is the top-left most and the last being the bottom-right most.

Comment: The function is not going to be recursive, the code is simply "find me the next object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has quite a deal of ambiguity from (what I suppose to be) the use of [`List<T>.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) method and your custom `Find` method which searches within a list.

I think this code may help you:

```
public CustomObject Find(List<CustomObject> list, CustomObject cfo)
{
    return list.Find(item => IsWithinBoxOf(cfo, item));
}

private bool IsWithinBoxOf(CustomObject cfo, CustomObject item)
{
    // return whether the item is within the box of cfo.
    return item.X <= cfo.X + 1 && item.Y <= cfo.Y + 1;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks! I will let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question but i'll give it a try anyway, maybe I'm lucky:

Write your Find-Method as generic, so that you can use a where clause with an interface in the signature.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ObjectsWithCoordinates
{
    public interface IObjWithCoordinates
    {
        int X { get; set; }
        int Y { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyObjWithCoordinates : IObjWithCoordinates
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T Find<T>(this IEnumerable<T> objects, int coordX, int coordY)
            where T : IObjWithCoordinates
        {
            if (objList == null)
                return;

            var objList = objects as IEnumerable<IObjWithCoordinates>;

            // Not needed, this is actually too defensive
            if (objList == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("objects must implement IObjWithCoordinates");

            return (T)objList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.X == coordX && o.Y == coordY);
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var obj1 = new MyObjWithCoordinates { X = 1, Y = 1, Name = "Name 1" };
            var obj2 = new MyObjWithCoordinates { X = 2, Y = 2, Name = "Name 2" };
            var obj3 = new MyObjWithCoordinates { X = 3, Y = 3, Name = "Name 3" };

            var coordObjList = new List<MyObjWithCoordinates> { obj1, obj2, obj3 };

            Console.WriteLine(coordObjList.Find(2, 2).Name);
            // Result: "Name 2"
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

> Short explanation:
>
> The trick is the static extension-Method which constrains itself to
>   objects that use your defined Interface (where T : Interface). This way you can be sure that
>   any kind of object you have in your list will be searchable by the X/Y
>   properties. From there you can just call the Find-Method on any generic List that uses your interface.
>
> Change as you whish/need.

Comment: Interesting. Where do the coordx and coordy get initiated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object (box in this case) in the predicate function that you pass into Find.

```
Rectangle box = new Rectangle(2, 2, 10, 10);

List<Point> pointList = new List<Point>();
pointList.Add(new Point(0, 0));
pointList.Add(new Point(3, 3));
pointList.Add(new Point(5, 4));
pointList.Add(new Point(20, 20));

Predicate<Point> firstPointInBoxPredicate = (Point p) =>
{
    return box.Contains(p);
};

Point firstPoint = pointList.Find(firstPointInBoxPredicate); // firstPoint = x: 3, y: 3
```